# One function to subscribe and return value - improve on functional purity?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am working on a project that receives humidity data from a raspberry pi sensor connected to a backend. In Angular Component, I want to display the data. I want to work as functional and pure as possible. However I feel very doubtful about my approach and would wish for some feedback.

`getAllHumidities()` does two things:

- subscribes to an Observable, and returns the data in a functional way.
- saves the Subscription as "humiditySubscription", but as a side effect.

I feel like `getAllHumidities()` isn't written under best practice thinking. Can and should I avoid creating the two component properties?

```
export class HumidityListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  humidities: Humidity[];
  humiditySubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private humidityService: HumidityService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.humidities = this.getAllHumidities();
  }

  getAllHumidities(): Humidity[] {
    let humidities: Humidity[];
    this.humiditySubscription = this.humidityService.getAll().subscribe(data => {
      humidities = data;
    });
    return humidities;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.humiditySubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know rxjs store ?

Comment: no, do you recommend using it here?

Comment: yeah, you can use it. just need to declare selector for humidities and you can use it in html file.you doesn't  need to subscribe it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure what is the purpose of the return value from the getAllHumidities() function. 
if you are subscribing, the humidity variable most likely to update only after the function will finish her job.

a nice and recommended way to get the data and unsubscribing **automatically** from the observable is by using the `async` **pipe**.

***in the component:***

```
humidities$: Observable<Humidity[]> = this.humidityService.getAll();

constructor(private humidityService: HumidityService) { }

ngOnInit() { }
```

***in the HTML template:***

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(humidities$ | async) as humidities">
...
use the feched humidities
...
</ng-container>
```

more information about [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe).

Comment: this looks very elegant, thank you. If I was to truncate the array to the first 100 elements, how would I do this though?

Comment: this is a the power of rxjs Observables, you can pipe them like this:

humidities$: Observable<Humidity[]> = this.humidityService.getAll().pipe(map((humidities)=>{
   return humidities.splice(0,100)
}));

Comment: perfection, thank you! I am wondering though,  I don't use the constructor, nor do I use ngOnInit. Do you think this is best practice to declare AND assign the value outside of a function?

Comment: if it is just to set the service function to the humidities$ variable I don't see why not, but if it is a more complex one (pipes), I think you right  and it is better to put it in the constructor or ngOnInit, or even dedicate a function that will be called from them to set the observable pipe.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need the `getAllHumidities` function. You can simply subscribe to your service `onInit`.
This will keep your `humidities` var always up to date.

Try this out:

```
humidities: Humidity[] = [];

constructor(
   public humidityService: HumidityService
) { }

ngOnInit() {
   this.humidityService.getAll().subscribe((data: Humidity) => {
      this.humidities = data;
   });
}
```

Or if you want it realy short in your html:

```
<div *ngIf="(this.humidityService.getAll() | async) as humidities">
   // The slice pipe will give you the value at the index 0 to 5
   <div *ngFor="let humiditie of humidities | slice:0:5; let i = index">
      Index: {{i}} <br> 
      Value: {{humiditie}}
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how do I unsubscribe?

Comment: Actually you don't need to do this manually. Angular will do this for you.